# How to make ListView height dynamic?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` and underneath is a `StackLayout`. I'm trying to make the `ListView` height grow as more rows are added to it (using a command in the `StackLayout`) with just the use of XAML. What's happening is the ListView is height is too big and the page ends up scrollable with the `StackLayout` all the way down

Here's my code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
     <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="10" Color="Transparent/>
     <StackLayout>
          <Label Style="{StaticResource AXASOL_Label_H1}" TextColor="White" Text="Do you have Dependents?" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     </StackLayout>
     <ListView>
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                   </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
     </StackLayout>
 </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a `Grid` instead of a `StackLayout`. Make sure the `Row` containing the `ListView` has it's `Height="*"` set.

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Do you have Dependents?" />

     <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Click" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</Grid>
```

codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    Items.Add(new Item("bla"));
    Items.Add(new Item("blub"));
    Items.Add(new Item("blubber"));
 }

  public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

  private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Items.Add(new Item("test"));
  }
}

public class Item
{
  public Item(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This will make all `Rows` with `Height="Auto"` take as much space as their content needs and the `Row` containing the `ListView` will fill up all the remaining space.

Comment: I tried this but as the list grows the last row doesn't go down

Comment: @AlfieMcNarutoad I edited my post. Button click will add a new item to the listview now. I dont understand what you mean by last row doesn't go down. What do you want to happen on adding a new item?

Comment: @AlfieMcNarutoad Can you try and set the Height of the row containing the ListView to `Auto`? Does this fix your issue?

Comment: I tried that as well earlier but with no luck. I think this goes back to the unmanaged and managed layouts rule